# how to fix "is missing its "caliper.blockchain" string attribute" in hyperledger caliper

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

Im trying to monitor my blockchain with hyperledger caliper. I created my own benchmark file by using one from the templates given in the repo. but I am getting this error

```
Error: Network configuration file "F:Blockchain\hyperledger-caliper\networks\fabric\docker-compose\3org1peercouchdb\docker-compose.yaml" is missing its "caliper.blockchain" string attribute
at Function.assertConfigurationFilePaths (F:\SE\3rd_Year\FYP\Blockchain\hyperledger-caliper\node_modules\@hyperledger\caliper-core\lib\common\utils\caliper-utils.js:75:19)
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

The problem is with the network configuration file that you are giving to Caliper. According to the **[official documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.2/fabric-config/new/#network-configuration-file-reference) of Hyperledger Caliper**, the networking configuration consists of an *YAML network configuration file*. This file needs to have an **object *caliper***, since it's *Required* and an *Non-empty object*, with an **attribute *blockchain*** within, that is *Required* and *Non-empty string*. Your log says that this object, and specific the attribute, are missing in the file you are specifying.

### SOLUTION

The file you specify is a docker-composer file. The network configuration file for your Fabric blockhain should be similar to, for example, the one at 'networks/fabric/v1/v1.4.1/2org1peercouchdb/fabric-go.yaml' that contains the network configuration parameters required by the Hyperledger Caliper and that manages the docker containers at the attribute *commmand* within the *caliper* object.

You can get those files at [caliper github repository](https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper-benchmarks) and also check the Hyperledger Caliper [official documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.2/getting-started/) for a better understanding.

### Example

You should have a network configuration file that specifies the blockhain that you are using, on the attribute ***caliper.blockchain***, and how are the docker containers managed, on the attribute ***caliper.command*** (just like the remaining and required parameters). For example:

```
...
caliper:
  blockchain: fabric
  command:
    start: export FABRIC_VERSION=1.4.0;export FABRIC_CA_VERSION=1.4.0;docker-compose -f networks/fabric/docker-compose/2org1peercouchdb/docker-compose.yaml up -d;sleep 3s
    end: docker-compose -f networks/fabric/docker-compose/2org1peercouchdb/docker-compose.yaml down;(test -z \"$(docker ps -aq)\") || docker rm $(docker ps -aq);(test -z \"$(docker images dev* -q)\") || docker rmi $(docker images dev* -q);rm -rf /tmp/hfc-*
  ...
...
```

### Notes

I'm using JSON files as network configuration files to Hyperledger Sawtooth and Ethereum, with Hyperledger Caliper. However, I'm not sure if a JSON file works on Fabric benchmarking.